# Prevent click on other item than the swiped item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, slide

**TLDR;**

How to prevent click on other item when there was already an item swiped open or was going to close.

Every item in the list has detail page (upon tap/click) and swipe-able.

**Actual behavior**

1. Swipe on the item (Burt Bear) to reveal the option.
2. Tap/click on the swiped item (Burt Bear) area (not the Delete) to remove option, works fine.

[image]

**Actual usage**

3. Swipe on the item (Burt Bear) to reveal the option.
4. Click on the item OTHER THAN the swiped item (Charlie Cheetah) and expect to remove option. BOOM! The detail page for the clicked item (Charlie Cheetah) was shown instead.

[image]

**Fact**

The actual usage was based on iPhone Whatsapp app. When u swiped a chat, then u tap on other chat, it will close the options and WILL NOT open the chat you just tapped.

Comment: I think that's a bug, or something wrong with your code. If you are using Ionic 4, you may want to report this on the Ionic Framework Github page (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues) as it seems to be a bug. I am currently using swipable items in Ionic v3 and not experiencing such issues.

Comment: Hi @IkennaAnthonyOkafor, when u swiped an item, and tapped on another item, the swiped item will closed am I right? But will the "another" item's `(click)` get triggered too?